# Chapter header with super huge numbers

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to get the chapter heading to look like this
[image: Chapter heading]

I am using the following code but the number are still so small

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushright\fontsize{80}{110}\bfseries}{\fontseries{bc}\fontsize{100}{130}\textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\\Huge\bfseries}
```

Can you help??

Comment: Please _always_ post the complete (small) document. In this case you haven't shown the important part, which fonts you are using. Most likely the log file gives a warning about the font size. If you are using Computer Modern, add \usepackage{fix-cm}

Comment: What document class are you using? If it is `memoir`, see Lars Madsen's (aka. daleif's) [collection of chapter styles](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you tried `resizebox` from the `graphicx` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you seek?

Your code is basically correct, with some typo though. package `fix-cm` is required in such case.  Since you provided only partial code, I add some basic lines including `\selectfont` and `xcolor` to make it run.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushright
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter name}
some text
\end{document}
```