# Chapter style right side large number

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm trying to get a Chapter style in overleaf like the one in the picture. However, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGEE{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}} 
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\HUGEE\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
text here
\end{document}
```

But I don't get the 1 large enough... can anybody help?

[image: Like this]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You are right! I changed it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139366/chapter-header-with-super-huge-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `type1cm` to get arbitrarily large text:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{type1cm}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\newcommand\HUGEE{\fontsize{5cm}{6cm}\selectfont} 
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\HUGEE\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
text here
\end{document}
```

[image]